# Angular app compiles but shows blank page

Tags: angular, typescript

So I was trying to write a client for a webapplication in Angular.
I initialized it with `ng new client`, served at that point it shows the default webpage.

Then changed the `app.component.{html, css, ts}` files and added a service with `ng generate service quote` and a Typescript-class (`Quote.ts`).
Keep in mind that those files, included as a page on another Angular project, work just fine.
On it's own, however, they don't:

When I run `ng serve` I get those messages:

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2019-01-02T20:34:57.478Z
Hash: 23d31db4a8a333ef9adb
Time: 7407ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 14.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 223 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.31 MB [initial] [rendered]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

When I then open a browser (tried it with different ones) on `localhost:4200` it just shows a blank page.
The display page's source is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Client</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

In the browser's cosole are the following errors:

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js?
[sm]:1 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> Location]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> Location]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Location!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:717)
    at resolveToken (core.js:954)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:898)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:795)
    at resolveToken (core.js:954)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:898)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:795)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:17656)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:18345)
    at resolveDep (core.js:18716)

main.ts:12
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> Location]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> Location]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Location!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:717)
    at resolveToken (core.js:954)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:898)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:795)
    at resolveToken (core.js:954)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:898)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:795)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:17656)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:18345)
    at resolveDep (core.js:18716)
```

**That is my code:**
**app.component.css** (It does not change anything if you remove all the css code.)

```
.center {
    border: 3px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.quote {
    padding: 30px;
}

button {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

**app.component.html** (Even is you remove the angular specific part, it does not show anything.)

```
<div class=center>
  <div class="quote">
      <pre>{{ quotes[index].body }}</pre>
  </div>
  <div>
      <button>-1</button>
      <button>+1</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { QuoteService } from './quote.service';
import { Quote } from './Quote';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public currentQuote: Quote;

    public constructor(
        private location: Location,
        private quoteService: QuoteService) {
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.currentQuote = this.quoteService.getRandomQuote();
    }
}
```

**quote.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Quote } from './Quote';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class QuoteService {
    private quotes: Quote[];
    public index: number;

    public constructor(/*private httpClient: HttpClient*/) {
        this.quotes = [     // This should be pulled from a server at some point
            new Quote(0, new Date(2018, 11, 13), "some text", 0, 0),
            new Quote(1, new Date(2018, 11, 13), "some text", 5, 1),
            new Quote(5, new Date(2018, 11, 15), "some text", 0, -1),
            new Quote(3, new Date(2018, 11, 16), "some text", -2, 0)
        ];
    }

    public getRandomQuote(): Quote {
        let newI: number;
        let i = 0;
        while((newI = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.quotes.length)) == this.index && i < 10) i++;
        this.index = newI;
        return this.quotes[this.index];
    }
}
```

**Quotes.ts**

```
export class Quote {
    public id: number;      // The unique id of the quote
    public date: Date;      // The date of the quote
    public body: string;    // The actual quote, including the participants and formatting
    public rating: number;  // The global rating on the quote as sum of all votes
    public vote: number;    // The user's own vote for the quote

    public constructor(id:number, date:Date, body:string, rating:number, vote:number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.body = body;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.vote = vote;
    }
}
```

All the other files are still how they got generated.

Here is the tree of the `src` subfolder:

```
src
├── app
│   ├── app.component.css
│   ├── app.component.html
│   ├── app.component.spec.ts
│   ├── app.component.ts
│   ├── app.module.ts
│   ├── quote.service.spec.ts
│   ├── quote.service.ts
│   └── Quote.ts
├── assets
├── browserslist
├── environments
│   ├── environment.prod.ts
│   └── environment.ts
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── karma.conf.js
├── main.ts
├── polyfills.ts
├── styles.css
├── test.ts
├── tsconfig.app.json
├── tsconfig.spec.json
└── tslint.json
```

Here is the code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1jpvn2).

I would be really happy if you could help me!

Comment: Did you check the console for any errors ?

Comment: If these five files are the entirety of your project, you are missing a router and a bootstrap.

Comment: Please provide a verifiable sample on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: @SachinGupta It compiles sucessfully.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I added the tree of the src folder in my post above.

Comment: If you inspect the rendered page, does it appear to have the correct content?

Comment: How do you run the application? What's the URL in he browser location bar? Given that your component doesn't have any property named quotes nor any property named index, what happens when you remove {{ quotes[index].body }} from the HTML template? And, as you were asked in the first comment what is in the browser console?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I added the source of the rendered page above. I guess it is normal for a Angular-page to look like this?

@JBNizet How I run it and the console output can now be seen above.
If you remove the `{{ quotes[index].body }}` and replace it with `test` for example, nothing changes, you still don't see anything.

Comment: What is printed in the **browser** console? Not your terminal. The browser console. The one you get when hitting F12 or Cmd-Alt-I in your browser, and then selecting the tab named "Console". And what is the URL in the location bar of your browser?

Comment: @JBNizet Or sorry, my bad. Somehow I forgot to look there. Two errors are thrown, now shown above. Do you also need the "error context"?
The URL is just http://localhost:4200/.

Comment: Now the error is clear: there is no service of type Location, so you can't have that in the constructor of your component. You're not using it anyway, so it's useless. There is a service of type Location in Angular, but it's another Location type, from the `@angular/router` module, that you're not using in your app. The browser console should always be opened while you develop. Any runtime error will appear there.

Comment: Your error says 'No provider for `Location`. You have `private location: Location` in your constructor of `AppComponent`, but you don't import `Location` anywhere. This is likely your bug, or at least one of them.

Comment: Thanks guys. After removing `private location: Location` and changing the html-file to display `currentVote` instead of an array-element that doesn't exist, everything seems to be fine!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem was the `private location: Location` in the constructor of app.component.ts, since it was not imported. Removing that unused line fixed that issue of nothing showing on screen.